# Pass item from ngFor on click to an Object of other page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I´m trying to push an item from my ngFor-Loop to an Object of another page. Unfortunately I don´t access to the Object.

**HTML home.html**

```
  <ion-card class="card card-ios" *ngFor="let card of cardArray; let i = index">
  ....
  <button class="favButton" ion-button icon-start clear (click)="addFavourite(card, i)">
```

**JS home.ts**

```
public cardFavouriteArray: any = [];
cardFavouriteArray: any = [];

addFavourite(card, i) {
  this.cardFavouriteArray.push(card);
}
```

**HTML favourites.html**

```
<ion-card class="card card-ios" *ngFor="let card of favouriteArray; let i = index">
```

**JS favourites.ts**

```
favouriteArray: any = [];

 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.favouriteArray = this.cardFavouriteArray;
 }
```

This do not work. I get an issue *`"property "cardFavouriteArray" does not exist on type FavouritesPage.`*

Comment: Your favourite file doesnt have a `this.cardFavouriteArray`

Comment: declare your variable as cardFavouriteArray:any[]=[] (you forget declare as array of any). If you want to "share" a variable between component you need use a service and a variable in this services to store the data

Comment: What is the relation between favourite component and home component , parent-child or sibling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider here passing favorite `favorite` object while navigating between the pages. Thereafter once you land on the page. On that component look for the passed object

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

addFavourite(card, i) {
  this.cardFavouriteArray.push(card);
}

navigateToOtherPage(){

    this.navCtrl.push(FavoritesPage, this.cardFavouriteArray);
}
```

**Code**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
class OtherPage {
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     console.log("navParams", navParams)
  }
}
```

Read more on [`NavController`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Answer (score 0):

### How to solve it with `localStorage`

We can use `localStorage`'s `.getItem` and `.setItem` to keep the information between pages. If you weren't writing in a Framework, this would probably be the way to go.

```
addFavourite(card, i) {
  this.cardFavouriteArray.push(card);
  localStorage.setItem('cardFavouriteArray', JSON.stringify(this.cardFavouriteArray))
}
...
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.favouriteArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardFavouriteArray'));
}
```

Comment: This question have been specifically asked for **Angular** not *AngularJS*

Comment: Oh, I missed that, my apologies.